# Error Call to a member function format() on string , En formulario Symfony

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Tengo el siguiente formulario en symfony:

```
->add('horaI', ChoiceType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Hora Inicio',
      'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una hora',
      'attr' => array(
                 'class' => 'form-name form-control'
                ),
      'choices'  => array(
                '08:00' => '8:00',
                '09:00' => '9:00',
                '10:00' => '10:00',
                '11:00' => '11:00',
                '12:00' => '12:00',
                '13:00' => '13:00',
                '14:00' => '14:00',
                '15:00' => '15:00',
                '16:00' => '16:00',
                '17:00' => '17:00',
)))
```

date es de formato time, entonces al guardar el formulario me muestra este error: Error Call to a member function format() on string.

Pensaba 2 soluciones un datapicker con este bundle:
https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle

Pero el mismo no muestra solo las horas sino también las cabeceras del mes y año, además horas que no necesito tomar en cuenta y que pueden hacer que el usuario escoja mal.

Este es el problema. Estoy trabajando con symfony 3.2.x

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que encontre es cada item transformarlo al tipo datetime según un ejemplo de la documentación de symfony:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by

El código quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
->add('horaI', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Hora Inicio',
            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una hora',
            'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-name form-control'
            ),
        'choices' => array(
    '08:00' => new \DateTime('08:00'),
    '09:00' => new \DateTime('09:00'),
    '10:00' => new \DateTime('10:00'),
    '11:00' => new \DateTime('11:00'),
    '12:00' => new \DateTime('12:00'),
    '13:00' => new \DateTime('13:00'),
    '14:00' => new \DateTime('14:00'),
    '15:00' => new \DateTime('15:00'),
    '16:00' => new \DateTime('16:00'),
    '17:00' => new \DateTime('17:00'),
)))
```

Espero les ayude.

Saludos

Comment: Si esta es la respuesta que solucionó tu pregunta, por favor, márcala como respuesta aceptada para que la pregunta quede cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

La solución a tu problema puede ser usando el TimeType proporcionado por Symfony

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html